# Where should the q3config.cfg file be?

Tags: quake-3

I've installed Quake 3 with the Q3 Pro Installer, and I'm not sure where the thing put my `q3config.cfg` file, if at all.

Now, I know that the file is usually in `[my directory of choice]\baseq3`, but the Pro Installer puts the file somewhere in my `AppData` folder, and I can't bloody remember where it specifically is!

I faintly remember that it is supposed to be somewhere inside/close to `AppData/Local/Temp/`, but I've searched there with no results.

Where exactly can I find my `q3config.cfg`? If the installer doesn't place one to begin with, where should I place it?

Comment: I have installed quake 3 using the [pro installer](http://planetquake.gamespy.com/View.php?view=Quake3.Detail&id=2365) and searched my entire hard drive for the file, but it's simply not there. I tried running the game once, then searched for it again (some games create files at first startup) but still no q3config.cfg. I'm afraid your file does not come with the pro installer.

Comment: @Kevin I said It was somewhere inside AppData. Check the answer I posted myself.

Comment: I said I searched for it, that means for me searched for it in my entire hard drive. The file simply does not exist on my computer.

Comment: I have also checked that location now to be sure, but the directory 'C:\Users\[My name]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\' does not contain the folder 'quake3' only a sony folder which contains CMA (vita stuff).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My installation directory for Quake 3:

-`C:\Program Files (x86)\Quake3`

The pro installer put the `q3config.cfg` file in:

-`C:\Users\[My name]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Quake3`

Comment: For info, the AppData folder is hidden by default. You need to search the drive or change view option to access it.

Comment: @Pierre I gotta say this is pretty nostalgic. With that outta the way you can still search the folder if you open it with %appdata%

Answer (score 2):

That file was not included in that installer of Quake III, Sorry mate.

Comment: I think it was. Check the question again ;)

Comment: Oh well, I tried to help! with some good feedback!

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using the search function of windows? In windows 7 in the upper right of your windows explorer, ctrl+f for older windows'. Going to the AppData folder first will search from there I believe.